# How can I control what is rendered by json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, rendering

I'm using Typeahead to display a drop-down list of suggestions:

**Controller:**

```
def typeahead
  render json: User.where(name: params[:query])
end
```

**View:**

```
<input type="text" id="typeahead">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY', 
    limit: 50
  });
  bloodhound.initialize();

  $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
  });

  $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum, name) {
    doSomething(datum.id);
  });
</script>
```

And it displays a list of `User.name`s. How could I render, say, a `User.email` for every User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`displayKey` either expects the fieldname of the suggestion object to be displayed, or a function converts the suggestion object into a string.

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: function(suggestion){
        return suggestion.name + " " + suggestion.email; 
    },
    source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works to display the email! But is there a way to display both the email and the name? `displayKey: 'name', 'email',` just breaks the code altogether.

Comment: Do you know if I can render a partial instead of manually converting everything into a string?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with ruby on rails, can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this maybe?

```
render json: User.where(name: params[:query]).as_json(only: :email)
```

Comment: This returns "undefined" for each User, although the emails can't be undefined, because @freek's code worked.

Comment: What this did was to send you only emails as the server response. I guess this was a js question. I poked my head around the wrong one. Glad you got it working though :)